# Python regex: looking for a regex match close to a starting point

Tags: python, regex, string

I am wondering if it is possible to looking for a regex match close to a starting point. The distance between the starting point and the match is an initial parameter.

Imagine this scenario.

I have an input text, a starting point and a regex like these:

```
str_text = f" bla bla bla bla 12 bla blablabla@bla.com bla bla bla "

str_starting_point = "12"
str_regex = "[a-z0-9]\\S{0,64}[a-z0-9]@[a-z0-9\\-\\.]{0,252}[a-z0-9]\\.[a-z]{2,10}|[a-z0-9]@[a-z0-9\\-\\.]{0,252}[a-z0-9]\\.[a-z]{2,10}"

re.findall(str_regex, str_text)
['blablabla@bla.com']
```

Now I'm trying to search a match of the regex close to the starting point.
I'm trying using the regex above, but it doesn't work:

```
inf_lim = 0
sup_lim = 2
str_regex_composed = f" {str_starting_point} " + r"(\w+\s){" + f"{inf_lim},{sup_lim}" + "}" + f"{str_regex} "
re.findall(str_regex_composed, str_text)


Desired output: "blablabla@bla.com" or ""
```

Do you have solutions or advices?
Thanks

Comment: So you don't want the first or all the matches, but you want the match that is closer to a certain index of the string?

Comment: Did you think about searching in string from starting point instead of modifying the regex?

Comment: @alessandro308 correct

Comment: If you only need things following the delimiter, how about just trimming the string first? `str_text[str_text.find(str_starting_point):]`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the [finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) method and manually calculate which matches are closest using the api for the [match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), specifically for your problem, it seems like [start](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.start) would be what you want.